# google minidump_stackwalk displays the message 'XXX.dmp has no thread list'

Tags: macos, qt, x86, apple-m1, google-breakpad

My project is built on MAC M1 using QT 5.15.2, intended to be compiled for the x86_64 architecture. I integrated `Breakpad` to handle crash information. I deliberately triggered a crash, received the dump file saved by `Breakpad`, and then ran `minidump_stackwalk` with the dump file and previously saved debug symbol table as parameters. However, I received the following response:

I ensured that I followed the process to use `dump_syms` to generate symbol tables for my program, and I also confirmed that I compiled `dump_syms`, `minidump_stackwalk`, libbreakpad.a, and other tools on my local machine with the x86_64 architecture.

```
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5103: INFO: Minidump opened minidump 98B92624-7D80-4615-ADDA-F082F74861BE.dmp
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5233: INFO: Minidump not byte-swapping minidump
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 15 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 7 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 7 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 1197932545 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 6 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 1197932546 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 4 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 14 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 5 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5876: INFO: GetStream: type 3 not present
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump_processor.cc:158: ERROR: Minidump 98B92624-7D80-4615-ADDA-F082F74861BE.dmp has no thread list
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump_stackwalk.cc:107: ERROR: MinidumpProcessor::Process failed
2023-08-09 01:09:27: minidump.cc:5075: INFO: Minidump closing minidump
```

I suspected that I might not be using the Breakpad library correctly in my project, so I tried running several QTDemo projects from GitHub that were designed to test Breakpad. However, even when using minidump_stackwalk with these projects, I still received the same response.
Can I assume that Breakpad is no longer compatible for use with the x86_64 architecture on MAC M1?